# Convert rubik_solver.Move.Move to string in python

Tags: python, string

I know it is simple just use `str()` but this does not work because I have some kind of weird type.

I'm using the library `rubik_solver` to calculate a rubiks cube solve and the result the library gives me an array with the type `rubik_solver.Move.Move` (to look it up I used `type()`) inside. How can I convert this type to a string but keep the thing all in the array? I've already tried `repr()` and `str()` but I get the error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Move
```

Simplification of the code:

```
from rubik_solver import utils

cube = "wwywybyroboobbgbrybgyorygbogobbgrwywrgryorrgorwgwwowyg" # My Cube

solving = utils.solve(cube, "Kociemba")  # Solve it

# Convert to string
for i in solving: 
    solving[i] = repr(solving[i]) #This creates the problem because the thing inside of the Array is not a String
```

Comment: The problem isn't with `str` or `repr`, it's that you're trying to index `solving` with a `Move` object instead of an integer. The for loop should be `for i in range(len(solving)): solving[i] = str(solving[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically indexing the list with the elements themselves rather than their position indices.

```
for i in range(len(solving)):
    solving[i] = f"{solving[i]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert the array of rubik_solver.Move.Move type objects to array of strings. Try this

```
moves_as_strings = [str(x) for x in solving]
```

This converts each element in the array 'solving' to a string and creates a new array with these strings, finally the result is saved in the array 'moves_as_strings'.

The problem with your code is, as Ted mentioned, you are indexing the array using rubik_solver.Move.Move object instead of an integer.
ie solving[L'] instead of solving[0].

For loop gives you the element directly in python, if you want the index of the element you can use enumerate. Your code should be:

```
for i, move in enumerate(solving):
    solving[i] = str(move)
```